# How to launch Flutter app from the background using android_alarm_manager_plus

Tags: flutter, dart, alarmmanager, alarm

I am trying to create an alarm application that doesn't use/rely on the `flutter_local_notifications`.

This is obviously possible on Android as there are several apps that do this.

I want the `android_alarm_manager_plus` to open the app and so the user is presented with a certain screen where they can dismiss the alarm/snooze it.

Comment: did you find something? i also need this functionality

Comment: Check out this article, you might need to translate it > https://jja08111.github.io/flutter/flutter-alarm-app/